# Python Webscraping Vue Components

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the value marked in the picture extracted to be a variable, but it seems that when it is within Vue Components, bs4 is not doing the searching like i am expecting. Can anyone point me in the general direction as to how i would be able to extract the value from this document in Python?
Code is found below picture, thanks in advance.
[image: Wanted value to be extracted]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/steam/76561198060134880'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#print(soup.prettify())

div_list = soup.findAll({"class":'value'})

print(div_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the page is returning a json response you don't need beautifulsoup to parse it.

```
import requests
import json

URL = 'https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/steam/76561198060134880'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)

dict_of_response = json.loads(response.text)

obj_list = dict_of_response['data']['segments']

print(obj_list)
```

The `obj_list` variable now contains a list of dicts. Those dicts contain the data you want and now you only need to loop trough the list and do what you want with the data.